# HTTP request aborted due to the local channel being closed WCF error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.5, channelfactory

I have a simple WCF Service

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Interface
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Task<A> DoWorkAsync(A a);
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class A
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int B { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With the following implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Interface;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public async Task<A> DoWorkAsync(A a)
        {
            if (a.B <= 5)
            { // for 5% of calls make an exception
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Sleep", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                return a;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} No Sleep", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
                return a;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hosted in Console application

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var baseAddresses = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/service1");

            using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof (Service1), baseAddresses))
            {
                var serviceMetadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
                                              {
                                                  HttpGetEnabled = true,
                                                  MetadataExporter =
                                                  {
                                                      PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15
                                                  }
                                              };
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetadataBehavior);

                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Running, press Enter to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();

                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a Unit Test (using NUnit) that sends a few requests to the service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Interface;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace WcfTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Test
    {
        public const int NumberOfCalls = 100;

        [Test]
        public void UseService()
        {
            var baseAddresses = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/service1");

            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
                          {
                              SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(900)
                          };


            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(baseAddresses);

            using (var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, endpoint))
            {
                IService1 client = factory.CreateChannel();

                var r = new Random();

                try
                {
                    var seed = Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfCalls)
                        .Select(i => r.Next(6, 100)).ToList();

                    Console.WriteLine("Expected to fail: {0}", seed.Count(t => t <= 5));

                    var tasks = seed.Select(rnd => MakeACall(client, rnd)).ToArray();

                    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

                    Console.WriteLine("failed = {0}", tasks.Count(t => !t.Result));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Program.UseService.finally");
                    var c = client as IClientChannel;
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        c.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0} unique exceptions", UniqueExceptions.Count);
            foreach (var uniqueException in UniqueExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(uniqueException.Value);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> UniqueExceptions = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public async Task<bool> MakeACall(IService1 client, int rnd)
        {
            bool result = true;

            var a = new A
            {
                B = rnd
            };

            try
            {
                await client.DoWorkAsync(a);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var exInfo = e.ToString();

                var hasher = SHA256.Create();
                var hash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exInfo)));

                UniqueExceptions.TryAdd(hash, exInfo);

                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: when I run the the test I get 3 errors (I expect none):

1. two timeouts: one with 00:00:00.9000000 and another time varies but looks like this 00:00:00.6460000
2. and an exception like this `The HTTP request to 'http://localhost:8080/service1' was aborted.  This may be due to the local channel being closed while the request was still in progress.  If this behavior is not desired, then update your code so that it does not close the channel while request operations are still in progress. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.`

Why do these exceptions happen, especially the second one?

---

**Update:**

It seems setting the timeout of 900ms was a bad idea, starting from 1300ms timeout and 1400ms delay the 2d error went away. This is very strange and I still would like to know why does this happen.

The first error was due to WCF 'warmup' (or may be my implementation is simply bad) - if you get a bigger number, like 400 requests - the first time you run the test it fails with ~290 requests, the second time (if you are really fast) ~140 requets, 3d time - ~30 requests and after it if you run test very very fast - there are no errors.

Also if you are curious - try really huge numbers of requests, like 3000, you will get an interesting errors there too.

Comment: I think I'm missing why you're trying to enforce such a low timeout threshold?  I believe the default SendTimeout is 60 seconds, significantly higher than your 900ms - 1400ms range.

Comment: This sample is mostly educational, I was researching async/await in WCF and 900 ms range is just a way to make the test fail fast. But it is *a lot of time* to make a web call into a service that echos back the request.... so I see no reason for WCF to fail over it